# How to create custom c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource and refer in tomcat context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, c3p0

I have a tomcat application server and my DB connection is defined in context.xml and fetched the data source as a JNDI.

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

<Resource name="datasource/test" auth="Container"
                type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                    factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
                        user="abc"
                        password="abc123"
                        jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jacplus"
                        driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                        minPoolSize="2"
                        initialPoolSize="30"
                        maxPoolSize="50"
                        idleConnectionTestPeriod="600"
                        acquireRetryAttempts="30"/>
                        
 </Context>
```

rather than hardcoding the username and password here in context.xml.I want to store db credentials in aws secret manager and create the data source with retrieved DB credentials from aws secret manager.

to do this I created the following custom ComboPooledDataSource class.

```
import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractComboPooledDataSource;

import javax.naming.Referenceable;
import java.io.Serializable;

    public final class CustomComboPoolDataSource extends AbstractComboPooledDataSource implements Serializable, Referenceable {
    
    
    }



    import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolConfig;
    import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory;
    
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;
    
    import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolConfiguration;
    
    public class SecureTomcatDataSourceImpl extends DataSourceFactory {
    
        public SecureTomcatDataSourceImpl() {
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public DataSource createDataSource(Properties properties, Context context, boolean XA) throws SQLException {

String userName = getFromAWSSecretManager("username");
String password = getFromAWSSecretManager("password");
    
            PoolConfiguration poolProperties = SecureTomcatDataSourceImpl.parsePoolProperties(properties);
            PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig(properties);
    
            CustomComboPoolDataSource customDataSource = new CustomComboPoolDataSource();
            customDataSource.setProperties(properties);
            customDataSource.setUser(userName );
            customDataSource.setPassword(password);
    
            // The rest of the code is copied from Tomcat's DataSourceFactory.
            if (poolProperties.getDataSourceJNDI() != null && poolProperties.getDataSource() == null) {
               performJNDILookup(context, poolProperties);
            }
    
           
    
    
            return customDataSource;
        }
    
    }
```

**after that, i created a jar file from above implementation and put it in tomcat /lib folder.**

and I did the following modifications in Context.xml file in tomcat/conf folder.

```
<Resource name="datasource/test" auth="Container"
                    type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                        **factory="com.aws.rds.SecureTomcatDataSourceImpl"
                            user=""
                            password=""**
                            jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jacplus"
                            driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                            minPoolSize="2"
                            initialPoolSize="30"
                            maxPoolSize="50"
                            idleConnectionTestPeriod="600"
                            acquireRetryAttempts="30"/>
```

but when i start tomcat i am getting following exception.

> > thod failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException:
> > Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name
> > 'java:comp/env/datasource/test'; nested exception is
> > javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: JNDI object with
> > [java:comp/env/datasource/test] not found: JNDI implementation
> > returned null     at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
> > at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
> > at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
> > at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
> > at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> > at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
> > at
> > org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
> > at
> > org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
> > at
> > org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853)
> > at
> > org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
> > at
> > org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
> > at
> > org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
> > at
> > org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
> > at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4770)
> > at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5236)
> > at
> > org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
> > at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
> > at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
> > at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
> > at
> > org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
> > at
> > org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
> > at
> > java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> > at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> > at
> > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> > at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> > 
>
> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: JNDI object with
> [java:comp/env/datasource/test] not found: JNDI implementation
> returned null     at
> org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:158)
> at
> org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
> at
> org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:96)
> at
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:45)

I verified my DB credentials and DB configs are correct.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: _"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.javatechie.aws.rds.SecureTomcatDataSourceImpl"_. Tomcat can not find your custom class.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz Sorry my bad.I updated the stack trace. Tomcat can find my custom class now.

Answer (score 0):

You are extending [Tomcat JDBC](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)'s `ObjectFactory` to create your datasource, which returns `null` whenever the type attribute is not `javax.sql.DataSource`, `javax.sql.XADataSource` or `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` and **logs** the problem at a warning level (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/0f4630d48ac26dfa84131d32b88d7138c7f6c06c/modules/jdbc-pool/src/main/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSourceFactory.java#L206)).

If you set `type="javax.sql.DataSource"` it should work, but your solution has a dependency on **both** Tomcat JDBC and C3P0.

I would rather retrieve username and password and call [`setUser`](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/AbstractComboPooledDataSource.html#setUser-java.lang.String-) and [`setPassword`](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/AbstractComboPooledDataSource.html#setPassword-java.lang.String-) in the default constructor of `CustomComboPoolDataSource` and use the generic `BeanFactory` to configure it in Tomcat.